# Running 'grunt' command on mean.js app just stalling

Tags: gruntjs, windows-10, meanjs

I am following the installation guidelines as described on mean.js.org Everything seemed to install fine. I have all prereqs installed. I ran npm install after cloning the github repo and then tried to run grunt and I didnt get any errors however It seems to just be stalling on the command line. Last message on the command line is the "debugger is running on port 5858" and then it just sits there.

After some time the message

> [nodemon] watching 51,839 files - this might cause high cpu usage. To reduce use "--watch"

comes up.  I am on windows 10 and have all the latest versions of node,npm,grunt and mean.js. I am running the command line as admin.

Mean.js should be running on localhost:3000 but it is not.

Answer (score 0):

This is intended.

There is an application invoked by the `grunt` command and running in background, watching your files for changes. In default configuration: `nodemon` and `grunt-watch`.

This will execute specific tasks based on the files you edited, such as linting JS files or compiling LESS files.
The cmd will probably show something when you edit files in the projects directory.

Comment: Sorry, Should have been more specific with the question. It should be running on localhost:3000. There should be a message that says something like "running on localhost:3000" but it just sits after the nodeman message

Comment: Ok so I found out the problem was that I was running node 4.x and that is not compatible with mean.js at the moment. I switched to node v-0.12.7 and everything seems to be working fine. Thanks for the help Lucas